Distortion in a negative channel of the differential amplifier THS4505
I designed a single-ended to differential signal amplifier using a tool provided by Texas Instruments:

The source signal passes through a voltage follower (OPA810IDBVR), so the output resistance should basically be negligible. My problem is that there's an asymmetry, that is clearly visible in the oscillogram below (CH1 & CH2 = outputs, CH3 = input).
The output signal is sent through the 1 meter long cable and is terminated with a LPF (\$33\Omega/22 pF\$ RC filter) before it's supplied to an ADC differential input.

Can you suggest me any possible cause of this problem?
I also attach the application schematic (the voltage follower operational amplifier is outdated here):

Update 05/30/2024
I found the source of the problem - it was caused by exceeding voltage reference's max output current. After amplifying the current, this part of a problem was solved.
For anyone interested, there's the waveform of overloaded voltage reference's output in the photo (it should be stable \$1.50 V\$). :

Unfortunately, my problem doesn't end here. Although the differential amplifier output is not distorted anymore, the gain factor of both channels is asymmetric. Each output channel \$V_{PP}\$ should be equal to \$1.00 V\$.

I measured the equivalent resistances of both feedbacks and it's perfectly symmetric. However, I noticed that when I change the input signal from \$1.5 V_{PP} + 0.75 V_{DC}\$ to \$1 V_{PP} + 1 V_{DC}\$, it starts to look fine and the gain becomes exactly \$1.33 \dfrac{V}{V}\$ per channel. If anyone solved similar problem before, I'll be glad to read about your solutions, while I'm considering possible parameters' modification.


Check your scope probes for correct compensation.
Check that C4 and C9 are same capacitor values.

Update after OP edited question:
3. Check your supply rails are stable using the scope.  Always.  :-)

The probes are fine - the signal doesn't change when I swap the probes. C4 and C9 values are the same, but I can test a couple of different values.

What is output of IC1?

It's the exact same copy of its input - just like I meant it to run.

Where were the scope probes placed?  Were CH1 & CH2 right at the output pins of the U3?  Where was CH3 placed?

Remove both C4 & C9 & repeat the waveforms of your post.  Any difference?

Is CH1 or CH2 getting close to 0V or 5V?  CH2 seems to be getting close to +5V.  Datasheet suggests not letting either output get closer than 1V to each supply rail, ie: both outputs should stay between 1V & 4V.


CH1&CH2 looked the same before after the cable (also after disconnecting it entirely). CH3 was placed right at the output of IC1.
Removing C4 and C9 didn't result in any noticable change, besides a slight increase in noise.
Neither of channels got anywhere near to the threshold. As in the calculations, the output should not go beyond 0.5 - 2.5 range.

I found the source of the problem. It will be described in a question edit.
